# MySQL order by first or result

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    users 
where
    email = 'email@example.com'
    or
    address = '123456'
```

how I can have result of first conditions `email = 'email@example.com'` firs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    users 
where
    email = 'email@example.com'
    or
    address = '123456'

ORDER BY email = 'email@example.com'
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, by the use of a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    users 
where
    email = 'email@example.com'
    or
    address = '123456' 
order by 
    case 
        when email = 'email@example.com' then 1 
        else 2 
    end
```

Comment: Or just: `...ORDER BY email = 'email@example.com'`